# Are any optional missions missable?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm playing through True Vault Hunter mode with my Commando. I've read that it's best to skip all optional missions until you're level 50, so that the rewards will be better, but I'm worried about missing anything.

Are there any optional missions that are permanently missable if not done at a specific time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are NO optional quests you can miss out on. This is due to one reason:

NPCs rarely die.  As in, killed off. Even so, the NPCs Gearbox chose to die only give out story missions, missions that you can't "lose".  Some other NPCs will seem like enemies, but give out missions until you finish the entire chain, which usually results in fighting the NPCs themselves, so there's really no real way to lose out on missions.